# why the module-alias did not replace the alias path to original path

Tags: typescript

I want to transform the alias path in typescript project using [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias). First I install the module-alias:

```
yarn add module-alias
```

add config in `package.json` like this:

```
"_moduleAliases": {
    "@": "."
}
```

but when I use the @ to import module, shows error like this:

```
Cannot find module '@/auth/extension/AuthHandler'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?ts(2792)
```

the `AuthHandler` path was `src/auth/extension/AuthHandler`, why did not found the module? what should I do to make it work?

Comment: Hi @Dolphin, any luck with this since you posted? I am struggling with it too. The TS path works but not the JS one. Cheers

Comment: I solved this problem, but I did not remember how to solved it, I have already tried to read the code and still not figure out, it too far away. sorry. @Stf_F

Comment: No problem @Dolphin, thanks for taking the time to respond in any case. After several rounds of trials and errors I eventually found the issues(s). Cheers

Comment: The error asks to add below code in tsconfig.json:  
"moduleResolution": "node"

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**:

In index.ts/starter file

```js
import moduleAlias from "module-alias";
moduleAlias.addAlias("@fn", __dirname);
```

And the matching tsconfig declaration:

```json
[...]

    "paths": {
      "@fn/*": ["./src/*"]
    },

[...]
```

**Not so long, want to read**:

After battling with this one for quite a while, I ended up removing the `_moduleAlias` entry from the package.json and instead registering the alias in the index.ts as follows:

```js
moduleAlias.addAliases({
  "@fn/*": `${__dirname}/lib/src`,
});
```

This, however did not work straight away either. There were 2 issues with this snippet:

- The first issue is the greedy operator that skews the actual alias and path to the module where the alias should take effect, e.g instead of outputting:
  `/path/to/module/@aliased_folder/sub`, the use of the greedy operator led to this path:
  `@aliased_folder/sub`
- In my case the use of `__dirname` and the output folder `lib/src` created a duplication in the path, e.g: /path/to/module/lib/src/lib/src/aliased

I therefore ended up with the following working version:

```js
import moduleAlias from "module-alias";
moduleAlias.addAlias("@fn", __dirname);
```